# Force transition animation when same button is clicked

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have three buttons which, when clicked change the min and max of a `time.scale`.

Transitioning works well but I'm trying to force the transition animation to happen even when the scale has not changed i.e. when the user clicks the same button.

This is the update code:

```
function updateAxis(grp) {
    console.log(grp);
    var parsedDts = grp.map(function(d) {
        return parseDate(d);
    });
    var minDate = d3.min(parsedDts),
        maxDate = d3.max(parsedDts);

    var plotJ = d3.select("#yAxisG")

    //>> using [minDate, minDate] to try to force a transition even when clicking the same square
    var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, minDate]).range([0, 800]);
    var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient('bottom')
        .scale(x);
    plotJ.transition().delay(2000).call(axisY);

    var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, 800]);
    var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient('bottom')
        .scale(x);
    plotJ.transition().duration(2000).call(axisY);

}
```

I thought maybe to change the scale to `[minDate, minDate]` would force the animation, when re-clicking the same button, but it does not.

How can I force the animation when re-clicking the same button?

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Axis Testing</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #threeSquares {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 250px;
    }
    
    #barChart {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 80px;
        height: 250px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="threeSquares"></div>
    <div id="barChart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function squaresBasics() {
        var margin = {
                top: 35,
                right: 5,
                bottom: 5,
                left: 5
            },
            width = 70 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        return {
            margin: margin,
            width: width,
            height: height
        };
    }

    function getdta() {
        return {
            'label': ['year', 'day', 'month'],
            'dts': [
                ['1/1/2016', '1/1/2017'],
                ['1/1/2016', '2/1/2016'],
                ['1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016']
            ]
        };
    };

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;


    //############# SQUARES ###################
    function addSquares() {

        var dta = getdta();

        var basics = squaresBasics();
        var margin = basics.margin,
            width = basics.width,
            height = basics.height;

        //Create SVG element
        var SQsvg = d3.select("#threeSquares")
            .append("svg")
            .attr({
                "width": width + margin.left + margin.right,
                "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom,
                id: "squaresArea"
            });

        var SQg = SQsvg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        SQg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dta.label)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr({
                x: margin.left,
                y: function(d, i) {
                    return i * 65
                },
                "width": width,
                "height": 50,
                fill: "blue"
            })
            .on("click", up);

        SQg.selectAll("text")
            .data(dta.label)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d;
            })
            .attr({
                x: margin.left,
                y: function(d, i) {
                    return i * 65 + 20;
                },
                "font-family": "sans-serif",
                "font-size": "15px",
                fill: "white"
            })
            .on("click", up);


        function up(d, i) {
            //update bar chart when user selects a square
            var dta = getdta();
            updateAxis(dta.dts[i]);
        }

    }


    function addAxis() {
        var basics = squaresBasics();
        var margin = basics.margin,
            width = basics.width,
            height = basics.height;

        var dta = getdta();
        var dates = dta.dts[0];
        var parsedDts = dates.map(function(d) {
            return parseDate(d);
        });
        //console.log(d3.min(amounts));

        var minDate = d3.min(parsedDts),
            maxDate = d3.max(parsedDts);
        //console.log(minDate, maxDate)

        var svg = d3.select("#barChart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr({
                "width": 1000,
                "height": 500,
                id: "barChartPlot"
            });

        var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, 800]);
        //console.log(x(new Date(2017, 7, 1)))
        //console.log(dta.dts.length)
        // console.log((margin.left - axisPadding), (margin.top + height));

        var axisPadding = 2;
        var leftAxisGroup = svg
            .append('g')
            .attr({
                transform: 'translate(' + ((margin.left + 15) - axisPadding) + ',' + (margin.top + height) + ')',
                id: "yAxisG"
            });
        var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
            .orient('bottom').scale(x);

        leftAxisGroup.call(axisY);

    }


function updateAxis(grp) {
    console.log(grp);
    var parsedDts = grp.map(function(d) {
        return parseDate(d);
    });
    var minDate = d3.min(parsedDts),
        maxDate = d3.max(parsedDts);

    var plotJ = d3.select("#yAxisG")
    
    //>> using [minDate, minDate] to try to force a transition even when clicking the same square
    var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, minDate]).range([0, 800]);
    var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient('bottom')
        .scale(x);
    plotJ.transition().delay(2000).call(axisY);

    var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, 800]);
    var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient('bottom')
        .scale(x);
    plotJ.transition().duration(2000).call(axisY);

}

    addSquares();
    addAxis();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If it's already at the values you want it to transition to, what would the transition look like?

Comment: @Mark I'd like the dates to transition to nothing (hence the scale [minDate, minDate]) and then transition back out to where they were previously (the same position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replaced the function so that the first transition makes callback that calls the second transition. Seems to work.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Axis Testing</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #threeSquares {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            width: 70px;
            height: 250px;
        }

        #barChart {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 80px;
            height: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="threeSquares"></div>
    <div id="barChart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function squaresBasics() {
            var margin = {
                    top: 35,
                    right: 5,
                    bottom: 5,
                    left: 5
                },
                width = 70 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            return {
                margin: margin,
                width: width,
                height: height
            };
        }

        function getdta() {
            return {
                'label': ['year', 'day', 'month'],
                'dts': [
                    ['1/1/2016', '1/1/2017'],
                    ['1/1/2016', '2/1/2016'],
                    ['1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016']
                ]
            };
        };

        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;


        //############# SQUARES ###################
        function addSquares() {

            var dta = getdta();

            var basics = squaresBasics();
            var margin = basics.margin,
                width = basics.width,
                height = basics.height;

            //Create SVG element
            var SQsvg = d3.select("#threeSquares")
                          .append("svg")
                          .attr({
                              "width": width + margin.left + margin.right,
                              "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom,
                              id: "squaresArea"
                          });

            var SQg = SQsvg
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            SQg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dta.label)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr({
                   x: margin.left,
                   y: function(d, i) {
                       return i * 65
                   },
                   "width": width,
                   "height": 50,
                   fill: "blue"
               })
               .on("click", up);

            SQg.selectAll("text")
               .data(dta.label)
               .enter()
               .append("text")
               .text(function(d) {
                   return d;
               })
               .attr({
                   x: margin.left,
                   y: function(d, i) {
                       return i * 65 + 20;
                   },
                   "font-family": "sans-serif",
                   "font-size": "15px",
                   fill: "white"
               })
               .on("click", up);


            function up(d, i) {
                //update bar chart when user selects a square
                var dta = getdta();
                updateAxis(dta.dts[i]);
            }

        }


        function addAxis() {
            var basics = squaresBasics();
            var margin = basics.margin,
                width = basics.width,
                height = basics.height;

            var dta = getdta();
            var dates = dta.dts[0];
            var parsedDts = dates.map(function(d) {
                return parseDate(d);
            });
            //console.log(d3.min(amounts));

            var minDate = d3.min(parsedDts),
                maxDate = d3.max(parsedDts);
            //console.log(minDate, maxDate)

            var svg = d3.select("#barChart")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr({
                            "width": 1000,
                            "height": 500,
                            id: "barChartPlot"
                        });

            var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, 800]);
            //console.log(x(new Date(2017, 7, 1)))
            //console.log(dta.dts.length)
            // console.log((margin.left - axisPadding), (margin.top + height));

            var axisPadding = 2;
            var leftAxisGroup = svg
                    .append('g')
                    .attr({
                        transform: 'translate(' + ((margin.left + 15) - axisPadding) + ',' + (margin.top + height) + ')',
                        id: "yAxisG"
                    });
            var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
                          .orient('bottom').scale(x);

            leftAxisGroup.call(axisY);

        }


        function updateAxis(grp) {
            console.log(grp);
            var parsedDts = grp.map(function(d) {
                return parseDate(d);
            });
            var minDate = d3.min(parsedDts),
                maxDate = d3.max(parsedDts);

            var plotJ = d3.select("#yAxisG")

            //>> using [minDate, minDate] to try to force a transition even when clicking the same square
            var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, minDate]).range([0, 800]);
            var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
                          .orient('bottom')
                          .scale(x);

            plotJ.transition().delay(1000).each("end", function() {
                var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, 800]);
                var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
                              .orient('bottom')
                              .scale(x);
                plotJ.transition().duration(2000).call(axisY);

            }).call(axisY);

        }

        addSquares();
        addAxis();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
</body>

</html>
```